Is it possible to dynamically create airflow DAGs through a python script
The situation is like this:
I created an airflow DAG with a few tasks and I want to dynamically create, on request, copies of this DAG, the only thing different being the schedule. I tried writing a python script that creates a DAG object and a DAG run for it but it never works, sometimes the DAG run is created but when I try to interact with it in the airflow interface an error pops up saying the DAG is not in the DAG bag.
Honestly I'm not even sure this is the right approach for this issue, let me explain where I'm trying to go with all of this, maybe you guys can guide me in a better direction:
I have a Java application in which you can declare and create some items, and whenever an item is saved I'd like to create a DAG (with the same tasks everytime) and only difference being the schedule interval (and name and tags if possible); I thought this script idea would be the ideal answer but it doesn't seem to cooperate, looking for any solutions.
This is the code that I reached trying my script that creates DAGs idea:

from datetime import datetime

import airflow
from airflow.decorators import dag, task
from airflow.utils.state import State
from airflow.models.dagrun import DagRun
from airflow.utils.types import DagRunType

import random
import pendulum

def generate_dag_id():

# this is just a function to generate random ids for the dags, nothing interesting

    colors = ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "purple", "pink", "brown", "gray", "black", "white"]
    animals = ["cat", "dog", "bird", "fish", "horse", "cow", "sheep", "pig", "goat", "snake", "duck", "goose", "chicken"]
    
    list = colors + animals
    
    name = random.sample(list, 3)
    
    timestamp = f"{datetime.now().hour}{datetime.now().minute}"
    
    final_name = ''.join([word.capitalize() for word in name])+timestamp
    
    return final_name

def create_dynamic_dag(dynamic_dag_id, review_schedule, dag_default_args):

# this is my DAG definition, some mock tasks but even the final product
# will have the same tasks every time

    @dag(
        dag_id=dynamic_dag_id,  
        schedule=review_schedule,
        default_args=dag_default_args,
        tags=['dynamic', 'dag'],  
        description="Generated DAG"
    )
    def dynamic_generated_dag():
        @task(task_id='decorator_first_task')
        def first_task():
            return f"dynamic dag task 1"
        
        @task(task_id='decorator_second_task')
        def second_task():
            return f"dynamic dag task 2"
        
        first_task() >> second_task()
    
    generated_dag = dynamic_generated_dag()
    
    return generated_dag

def main():
    dynamic_dag_id = generate_dag_id()

    schedule = '* * * * *'  
    
    default_args = {
        'owner': 'airflow',
        'depends_on_past': False,
        'start_date': pendulum.today().subtract(days=1)
    }
    
    dynamic_dag = create_dynamic_dag(dynamic_dag_id, schedule, default_args)
    
    dag_run = DagRun(
        dag_id=dynamic_dag.dag_id,
        run_id=dynamic_dag_id,
        state=State.RUNNING,
        execution_date=pendulum.now('Europe/Athens'),
        run_type=DagRunType.MANUAL,
    )
    
    with airflow.utils.session.create_session() as session:
        session.add(dag_run)
        session.commit()
        
    print(f"Dynamic DAG '{dynamic_dag_id}' created and triggered.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

I also tried this way of starting the generated dag, instead of the session.add(dag_run) but also didnt work:
globals()[dag_id] = create_dag(dag_id, schedule, dag_number, default_args)

Probably important detail is that I placed this file and ran it from my airflow/dags folder.
